# Issue about conditions

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
    if (a && b && c) {
      setOrder(formatOrder(a, b, c));
    }

    if (!a && !b && !c) {
      setOrder("");
    }
```

This works as expected. But my question is if I change the condition with else, like this:

```
    if (a && b && c) {
      setOrder(setOptions(a, b, c));
    } else {
      setOrder("");
    }
```

it doesn't work correctly anymore.
Can someone explain me why? `Else` doesn't mean `!a && !b &&!c` ?

Comment: _"Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_ and add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Comment: See [DeMorgan's Law](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/truth_tables_and_logic.html).

Comment: Those two logical expressions are absolutely not the same.  "If I have tomato sauce, and also some salad, and some red wine"; the opposite is not "If I don't have tomato sauce, and I don't have some salad, and I don't have red wine".  This is pretty basic logic.

Comment: why not use a table of truth to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!(a && b && c)` is the same as `!a || !b || !c`, not `!a && !b && !c`

`!a && !b && !c` is the same as `!(a || b || c)`

This subject in Computer Science is called [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Here's an interactive demo of this:

```js
const updateFormulas = () => {
  const [a, b, c] = [A, B, C].map((cb) => cb.checked);
  document.querySelector("#and-positive").innerText = a && b && c;
  document.querySelector("#and-all-negative").innerText = !a && !b && !c;
  document.querySelector("#negative-and-positive").innerText = !(a && b && c);
  document.querySelector("#or-all-negative").innerText = !a || !b || !c;
  
  if (a && b && c) {
    document.querySelector("#if-and-positive").innerText = true;
    document.querySelector("#else-and-positive").innerText = false;
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#if-and-positive").innerText = false;
    document.querySelector("#else-and-positive").innerText = true;
  }
  
  if (a && b && c) {
    document.querySelector("#if-and-positive-2").innerText = true;
    document.querySelector("#if-and-all-negative").innerText = false;
  } else if (!a && !b && !c) {
    document.querySelector("#if-and-positive-2").innerText = false;
    document.querySelector("#if-and-all-negative").innerText = true;
  }
};

updateFormulas();

document.querySelectorAll(`input[type="checkbox"]`)
  .forEach((checkbox) => checkbox.addEventListener("change", updateFormulas));
```

```html
<label>a</label><input type="checkbox" id="A" />
<label>b</label><input type="checkbox" id="B" />
<label>c</label><input type="checkbox" id="C" />
<hr /> a &amp;&amp; b &amp;&amp; c = <span id="and-positive"></span>
<br /> !a &amp;&amp; !b &amp;&amp; !c = <span id="and-all-negative"></span>
<br /> !(a &amp;&amp; b &amp;&amp; c) = <span id="negative-and-positive"></span>
<br /> !a || !b || !c = <span id="or-all-negative"></span>
<hr /> 
if (a &amp;&amp; b &amp;&amp; c) <span id="if-and-positive"></span>
<br />
else <span id="else-and-positive"></span>
<hr />
if (a &amp;&amp; b &amp;&amp; c) <span id="if-and-positive-2"></span>
<br />
if (!a &amp;&amp; !b &amp;&amp; !c) <span id="if-and-all-negative"></span>
<hr />
```

Answer (score 1):

No it means `!(a && b && c)` which is the same as `!a || !b || !c`.

Think about what would happen with `a == true`, `b == false`, `c == true`?

In your original code you had **3 cases**: 1st condition met, 2nd condition met, and *no conditions met*; and my example just now fell into the latter (no conditions met).

But with your `else` example you have only **2 cases**: Condition met, condition not met, so the cases 2 and 3 of your original code are now combined.

Answer (score 0):

It actually works correctly. `else` is if the `if` condition is `false`.

In your case, the condition `a && b && c` will be `false` in the case of `!a || !b || !c`.

Comment: ok, so this is the issue basically, in else javascript evaluates as ```!a || !b || !c``` and not as ```!a && !b && c``` ?

Comment: @Katerin1122 it's not how js works, it's how logic works.

Comment: This is not specific to JavaScript at all. It's basic boolean logic. Think about the condition with parentheses. The logical negation of `(X)` is `!(X)`. The logical negation of `(a && b && c)` is `!(a && b && c)` which is equivalent to `!a || !b || !c`.

Comment: @Katerin1122 Yes - but I don't understand why you'd think it would be anything else? There is nothing special about how `else` is evaluated. It just means the condition is _not_ met. The condition "all of a, b and c are true"  isn't met as soon as _any_ one of them is false, not necessarily _all_ of them. If the condition is "I have bread, butter and salt" then surely you'd agree the condition isn't met if you are missing the butter even if you have bread and salt, right? This is pure logic and has nothing to do with JavaScript in particular